# Java code to copy files from one linux machine to another linux machine

Tags: java, copy

I wants to write a program to copy/create one file from linux machine to another linux/windows machine in java.
I tried below code,which will create one file in another windows machine..

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Example2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         String path = "\\\\10.15.0.166"+File.separator+"test";          

            String fname= path+File.separator+"Sample.pdf";
            File file = new File(fname);
            try {
                file.createNewFile();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Exists"+file.exists());
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();  
    }

}
```

It worked in WIndows to windows.
But when I tried from linux machine .it is creating folder in the linux machine itself.
Could any one help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like `FTP` to move files between unix machines.

[JSCH](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) is a good API for that.

You will need some user authentication tho.

Here is an example:

```
JSch jsch = new JSCH();
Session session = jsch.getSession(config.getUsername(), config.getHostname(), config.getPort()); //port is usually 22
session.setPassword(config.getPassword());

session.connect();

Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
ChannelSftp cFTP = (ChannelSftp) channel;

String sourceFile = "---", targetFile = "---";
cFTP.put(sourceFile , targetFile );

cFTP.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
```

Comment: Sorry. `cFTP`. Corrected.

Comment: I tried to run the program in linux in command line as shown below ,but getting compilation error   Could not find symbol \n                                        javac -cp .:/home/divya/jcsh-0.1.42.jar FileCopierOverNetwork.java
FileCopierOverNetwork.java:1: package com.jcraft.jsch does not exist
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
                      ^
FileCopierOverNetwork.java:2: package com.jcraft.jsch does not exist
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
                      
           ^
14 errors

Comment: /home/divya/**jcsh-0.1.42.jar** you must be mispelling the jar file name. The library should be **JSCH and not **JCSH**

Comment: Thanku..it compiled correctly...                                       But am getting error whe run the pgm.Exception in thread "main" com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: session is down
Do you know why this exception

Comment: Sorry again. I missed the `session.connect();` call before creating the channel.

Comment: Sorry am getting UnKnownHostKeyError

Comment: I corrected the above problem by setting session.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");before session.connect()

Answer (score 2):

To work the above application ,We have to add one more line in the above code,
session.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"); just before session.connect();
Complete program is

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;
import java.io.File;

public class test {
public static void main(String args[]) throws JSchException {

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession("user", "10.15.0.243", 22); //port is usually 22
    session.setPassword("password1.");
    session.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.connect();
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
    ChannelSftp cFTP = (ChannelSftp) channel;
    jsch.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    String sourceFile = "/home/divya/hi.txt", targetFile = "/home/user/test";
    try {

        cFTP.put(sourceFile , targetFile );
    } catch (SftpException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    cFTP.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
}
```

}

Regards

Divya

Comment: It works :) @DRD There was no put method available in session. Instead of 
 `session.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");`
i used `session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");`

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a file on another machine this way under Linux... You are using Windows share folders, which is not the way files are shared in Linux world. You have two choices :

1. either by connecting the two filesystems, with NFS for example (a
   kind of Unix file sharing), in such a way that the second filesystem
   is mounted on the first one so that a path will lead you to the
   second machine in a way similar to Windows file sharing paths.
2. either by using some protocol to transfer your file (FTP, RSYNC,
   etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet to copy files to another linux machine.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = null;
session = jsch.getSession("username","hostname",22);
session.setPassword("password");
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.connect();
ChannelSftp channel = null;
channel = (ChannelSftp)session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
File localFile = new File("localfilepath");
//If you want you can change the directory using the following line.
channel.cd(RemoteDirectoryPath)
channel.put(new FileInputStream(localFile),localFile.getName());
channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
```

For more details reach out [THIS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136165/java-code-to-copy-files-from-one-linux-machine-to-another-linux-machine) similar post